# In how many ways can this function be simplified?

Tags: javascript, arrays, generalization

I'm trying to simplify/generalize a function `foo_one` that traverses through a multidimensional array and sets all sub-array elements apart from the first one to have `null` values.

I was given only the first function, for which I should then find more ways to generalize it to still accomplish the intended purpose of `foo_one`.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

I've already implemented 2 other variations of the function and I like to have more if possible.

```
var arr = [
  [2, null, 2, null],
  [2, null, 2, null],
  [null, null, null, null],
  [null, null, null, null]
];

function foo_one() {
  for (let y = 0; y < arr.length - 1; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < arr.length - 1; x++) {
      if (arr[x + 1][y] != null) {
        if (arr[x + 1][y] == arr[x][y]) {
          arr[x][y] = arr[x][y] * 2;
          arr[x + 1][y] = null;
        }
        if (arr[x][y] == null) {
          arr[x][y] = arr[x + 1][y];
          arr[x + 1][y] = null;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function foo_two() {
  for (let y = 0; y < arr.length - 1; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < arr.length - 1; x++) {
      if (arr[x + 1][y] != null && arr[x + 1][y] == arr[x][y]) {
        arr[x][y] = arr[x][y] * 2;
        arr[x + 1][y] = null;
      }
    }
  }
}

function foo_three() {
  for (let y = 0; y < arr.length - 1; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < arr[y].length - 1; x++) {
      if (arr[x + 1][y] != null && arr[x + 1][y] == arr[x][y]) {
        arr[x][y] = arr[x][y] * 2;
        arr[x + 1][y] = null;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Output
[ [ 4, null, 4, null ],
  [ null, null, null, null ],
  [ null, null, null, null ],
  [ null, null, null, null ] ]
```

Comment: What is all that attempting to do, can you describe in English?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm just trying to generalize the first function into simpler versions. That's all

Comment: you don't specify what that function tries to do actually! please explain what is its role?

Comment: Looks like a school assignment

Comment: May be you can "club nested if statement" in single using && operator.

Comment: Why are you ignoring the last column? with "let x = 0; x < arr.length - 1; x++"? That means that if there are any 2's in the last column that match, they will be ignore?

Comment: Also, the first two foo methods are wrong because you don't take the second array's, within the array, length into account.

Comment: @evilReiko lol, its a work assignment

Comment: @CertainPerformance I've edited the question description to bring more clarity.

Comment: let arr = [
    [2, null, 2, null],
    [2, null, 2, null],
    [null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null]
];
function foo(){
    x = [];
    for (line in arr){
        for (items in line){
           if (arr[line][items]!= NaN) { x.push(parseInt(arr[line][items])*2)}}}
};
foo();
console.log(x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function foo_four(arr) {
   let yLoopCount = arr.length - 1,
       xArrLength = 0,
       currentRowValue = 0,
       nextRowValue = 0;

   for (let y = 0; y < yLoopCount; y++) {
     xArrLength = arr[y].length;  // arr[y].length - 1

     for (let x = 0; x < xArrLength; x++) {
       currentRowValue = arr[y][x];
       nextRowValue  = arr[y+1][x];

       if (currentRowValue && currentRowValue == nextRowValue) {
         arr[y][x] = currentRowValue * 2;
         arr[y+1][x] = null;
       }
    }

  return arr;
}


var arr = [
  [2, null, 2, null],
  [2, null, 2, null],
  [null, null, null, null],
  [null, null, null, null]
];

foo_four();

// Output
// [
//     [4, null, 4, null],
//     [null, null, null, null],
//     [null, null, null, null],
//     [null, null, null, null]
// ];
```

a) I'm looping through the last row as well.
b) It's a minor optimization if you create the variables outside the loop, and then reuse them.
c) It's a minor optimization if you're using variables to shorten any kind of deep reference. Diving into each subproperty takes time, like referencing `arr[y][x]` several times instead of `currentRowValue`.
d) I prefer to send the array as a parameter, and also return it, even if I change the array. Cleaner code in my book, and easier to debug.
e) Use variable (or method) names to explain what's going on.
f) By using variables, it's easier to debug.
g) I usually give all variables a starting value to describe what kind of type they are (empty array, object, number, string) so the next person can look at them and see what they are without having to read and process what the variable names means.

Comment: thank you. this is very clear and concise and I love you explanations

Answer (score 1):

The following rewriting is more efficient than the original post.

```
let arr = [
    [2, null, 2, null],
    [2, null, 2, null],
    [null, null, null, null],
    [null, null, null, null]
];

function foo_four(arr) {
    for (let y = 0, yl = arr.length - 1; y < yl; y++) {
        let currRow = arr[y];
        let nextRow = arr[y + 1];

        for (let x = 0, xl = nextRow.length - 1; x < xl; x++) {
            let currValue = currRow[x];

            if (currValue && currValue === nextRow[x]) {
                currRow[x] = currValue * 2;
                nextRow[x] = null;
            }
        }
    }
}

foo_four(arr);
console.log(arr);
// [
//     [4, null, 4, null],
//     [null, null, null, null],
//     [null, null, null, null],
//     [null, null, null, null]
// ];
```

Comment: thanks. this is efficient, but do couldn't there be a way to not use `nested if`?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the processing inside the nested loops more concise. Also, I don't see why you need to ignore the last column.

```js
function foo_four() {
  for (let y = 0; y < arr.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < arr.length - 1; x++) {
      arr[x][y] = arr[x][y] === null ? arr[x+1][y] : arr[x][y] * 2;
      arr[x + 1][y] = null;
    }
  }
}

var arr = [
  [2, null, 2, null],
  [2, null, 2, null],
  [null, null, null, null],
  [null, null, null, null]
];

foo_four();
console.log(arr);
```